# How to thread a specific computationally expensive callback

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community.

I am building a specific application where I have two subscriber callbacks as written below:

```
def callback1(msg):
    X = msg.X

def callback2(msg):
    desX = msg.desX
    publish(desX)
    while duration < 1 sec:
        if equal(X, desX):
            return True
    return False
```

The callbacks are oversimplified for easier understanding, and I also assume X is some global variable (or object attribute), so that both callbacks can access it.

*callback1* is a sensor measurement coming in at 20 Hz.

*callback2* is called on user request, but let's assume it can be called at more than 1 Hz.

In a single threaded mode, this will not work, since *callback2* blocks *callback1* and the sensor measurement is not read properly. I would like to implement this multi-threaded, but with following requirements:

1. *callback1* is blocking, i.e. two of them cannot be performed at the same time,
2. *callback2* is preemptable, i.e. if another call is made the previous one will be canceled,
3. It should be done in C++.

My initial idea was to have a separate callback queue for *callback2* and have the *callback1* in the global queue in the single-threaded callback manner, like mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Uses) under point 2.

I would like to know how to implement this given the additional requirement that the *callback2* is preemptable. Also, any other design recommendations are more than welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250331/how-to-thread-a-specific-computationally-expensive-callback/) by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-12-19**:
Why not have the two callbacks simply update the global/member variables and then implement the logic in a main loop or a roscpp Timer ? You could also use a ROS Action for *callback2* (instead of a plain subscriber)

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on 2016-12-19**:
In case of using a timer, what would be a good design? Have a timer which periodically checks if equal(X, desX), and takes into consideration the timestamp to publish False on exceeding the max duration? Also, regarding placing the logic in main, are there any pr's of doing that?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-12-19**:
You can do a `ros::Timer` that triggers every so often and does that check or you can have a while loop running at some `ros::Rate`. They are similar, although the ROS wiki recommends Timers.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-12-19**:
And here some more info: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates and http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Timers

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on 2016-12-20**:
Thanks a lot, this solution works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I decided to go with the solution of having multiple callback queues by adapting the answer found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/214629/multiple-callback-queues/).

*callback1* is thus kept in the global ROS queue, while *callback2* is run asynchronously.

To make the *callback2* preemptable, I added a variable which stores the time stamp of the most recent callback, and a check for a more recent time stamp in the while loop of the callback which is used for preemption. Some care had to be taken to avoid race condition, but it was rather simple with atomic variables or mutex locks.

---

Originally posted by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) with karma: 111 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(1) sounds like a pretty typical use for locks, or just a single callback queue.

(2) ROS doesn't natively support callback preemption. If you want it, you'll have to build it yourself. This probably means having a few locks or mutexes and inserting preemption points into your callback, where it can abort early if there's another callback waiting.

(3) Do it in C++

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-19**:
What about modelling this on top of Actions?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-19**:
Actionlib would make this easier, but even in actionlib, the server needs to have preemption points within the algorithm where it actively checks if the goal has been cancelled.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-19**:
Obviously. It would probably be good if the OP could describe his requirements in a bit more detail. I'm not sure whether we're not actually solving an xy-problem here.

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on 2016-12-19**:
I am aware this could be implemented using actionlib, but it seems like an overkill here? Could you please elaborate more on 1? Do you mean separating callback1 and callback2 into different single callback queues? If so, how would I spin that so that they don't block each other?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-19**:
you think actionlib is overkill, but creating your own solution isn't? I think you have it backwards.

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on 2016-12-20**:
IMHO if adding a Timer and two extra variables can solve it, then using actionlib is probably an overkill. But if that solution is the most maintainable one, I would definitely go for it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-20**:
From reading your own answer, I think actionlib would have been much cleaner and a more conceptually nicer way to model this all. But if it works for you the way you have it now, I'm not going to suggest anything different.

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on 2016-12-20**:
Thank you for the feedback! I will try implementing the solution using actionlib as well. I will post it here, since the way I imagined the solution to be did not seem that clean, so I might be missing something.

**Comment by [InderpreetSingh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28075/inderpreetsingh/) on 2020-06-03**:
Hi, I am running into the same problem, can you elaborate how did you finally solve it?